# how to set up layout in xml which could let the sibling take the free space?

Tags: android, layout

Three TextView and part #1, #3 could have different size. How to let other part get more space if it has less content?

The part #2, #3 should flow next to part#1.

1. part #1 has "aaa" and part #3 has "cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc" so ellipsis shows

+---------------------------------+

aaa | b | cccccccccccccccccc...

+---------------------------------+

2. both part #1 and part #3 have string too long so both shows ellipsis

+----------------------------------+

aaa aaa aaaaaa... | b | cccccccc...

+---------------------------------+

3. part #3 has less char so part #1 takes as much as it could (let part #3 take as less as it needs).

+---------------------------------+

aaa aaa aaaaaa aaaaaaaa... | b | c

+---------------------------------+

Tried this, but have to have part #1 with maxWidth, and will waste part#3's space if part#3 has less content.

Is there better way?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/part_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxWidth="150dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/part_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:text="::"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/part_1"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/part_3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/part_2"
    />=
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a `LinearLayout` ViewGroup, and the layout_weight property.

For example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:id="@+id/A"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/B"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/C"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In this example, the C TextView will be the width of the content. The A TextView will be 66% of the remaining width (2 out of 3 total weight), and the B TextView will take up the last 34% (1 out of 3 total weight) of the width.
You must use a LinearLayout as it is the only ViewGroup that supports layout_weight.

Comment: does not work if both part #1 and #3 have less content, the part# will still take 66%. And it is required part #2, #3 flow by #1.

Comment: If you have a strong need to lay your text out in this fashion, and the stock Views and ViewGroups are not working for you, you might consider creating a custom View to display your data.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this way:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/part_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"        
    android:singleLine="true" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/part_2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:text="::" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/part_3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you please clarify a bit what output you want so I it will help me give you a proper solution.

Comment: #2, #3 should flow by #1 (next to it without extra space). if there are space left for #1 or #3 the other should take it (itself should take space as less as possible).

Comment: Have a look on edited answer, is this what you want? If it is still not working for you than give me a proper visual example.

Comment: let #2 take all free space does not work. It needs to have #1, #2, #3 left aligned. Basically #1,#2,#3 left align and flow next. #1 and #3 should take as less space as possible. If after #1 and #3 have been placed there is still free space, the free space will be left at right side of the #3. The drawing in the question should explain it.